# Can't get dynamic images to work properly with css

Tags: html, css, dynamic, resize

Here's my html

```
<div id="contentBox" style="margin:0px auto; width:100%">      

    <div align="left" id="column1" style="float:left; margin:0; width:37%;">
            <ul class="tmo_list">
                <strong>
          Commercial Buildings<br><br>
          Shopping Centers<br><br>
          Dumpster Pads<br><br>
          Decks & Patio<br><br>
          Store Fronts<br><br>
          Restaurants<br><br>
          Drive Ways<br><br>
          Awnings<br><br>
                </strong>
            </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/pressurewashing.jpg"/>
    </div>


    <div align="right" id="column3" style="float:right; margin:0; width:37%;">
            <ul class="tmo_list">
                <strong>
          Office Buildings<br><br>
          Business Signs<br><br>
          Loading Docks<br><br>
          Rust Removal<br><br>
          Wood Fences<br><br>
          Gas Stations<br><br>
          Bus Stops<br><br>
          Homes<br><br>
                </strong>
            </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my css

```
.wrapper img {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto;
}
```

I've been reading a few tutorial's
mainly
http://www.fredparke.co.uk/blog/using-max-width-resize-images-dynamically
and
[How can I resize an image dynamically with CSS as the browser width/height changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684304/how-can-i-resize-an-image-dynamically-with-css-as-the-browser-width-height-chang)
and
[How to dynamically resize image in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586755/how-to-dynamically-resize-image-in-css)

with no luck, I'm tired of changing things... so frustrating, what I get is the image superimposed over column3, but never does the image resize...

Answer (score 1):

It does resize, Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/

What browser are you using? I tried in `mozilla and chrome`.

Also make sure you have a large sized image, If you have a small image, your css wont stretch, here is the fiddle with the small image
http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/1/

here is the 3 column layout you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/3/

Comment: hrmmm... yes, it did have that affect as well, (dropping below column1), I was trying to maintain some columns using division.  Initially I had something akin to <div align="left" id="column1" style="float:left; margin:0; width:37%;"> for column2, but the image wasn't resizing, and column 3 was overlaying column 2... any idea how I can get the image to stay in the center column?

Comment: @thistleknot okay so you are trying to make 3 columns, text-image-text, did I get you right?

Comment: @thistleknot I am glad I could help, if this answers your question, could you please accept the answer

Comment: hmm, don't know why, but that only produced rows, not columns, and still didn't resize.  Works in the fiddler, just not on my damned webpage!!!  argghhhh.  here's what it looks like http://imgur.com/ZrAEbeZ

Comment: @thistleknot can you give acutal link to the website or fiddle the whole page so I can see where the problem is?

Comment: I can confirm it works in fiddle, but not in my page, here's some screenshots.  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/75FM7/ screenshots http://imgur.com/a8YmDEg (center is fiddle, outer is my page)

Comment: @thistleknot bud, i cant tell anything from image, I got to see the code to figure out the issue, could you provide the link for your page?

Comment: I don't have it up, I sent you the fiddle code, did you see it?  same post as the lastest imgur  here it is again  jsfiddle.net/75FM7